# EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 instances: running `apt-get update` results in "Hash Sum mismatch"

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apt, ubuntu-14.04

Every time I create a new AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 14.04 (using `ami-a182b391`, as found from [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)) and then immediately run `sudo apt-get -y update`, it gives me an error.

Here's the OS info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Here's the failing apt command:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y update
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release             
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [1,064 kB]   
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources [6,399 kB]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63.5 kB]             
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en     
Get:5 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [196 kB]
Get:6 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [114 kB]
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages 
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US     
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US 
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [80.3 kB]       
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [21.9 kB]  
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [267 kB]  
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [101 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en    
Fetched 8,308 kB in 4s (1,678 kB/s)               
W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've literally done nothing else on the box besides boot it and run this command, and I've tried with multiple instances and it always happens.

I've found a workaround:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
$ sudo apt-get -y update
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
...
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [136 kB]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [56.8 kB]
Fetched 21.9 MB in 5s (3,724 kB/s)                                 
Reading package lists... Done
```

But 1) why is this error happening, 2) is this workaround "OK" to do?

Answer (score 3):

Relevant post with some answers and a related bug report.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/972077

TLDR; 1) it's an issue with the amazon mirror and 2) this is a common workaround that is generally considered "ok" but annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a support ticket with AWS and the issue is no longer occurring. I believe they refreshed/fixed some of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

**Security Groups -> Outbound**

```
*   ALL Traffic ALL     ALL     0.0.0.0/0   Allow
```

Please allow Outbound, if you want to connect to external servers like google.com
or even want to update- sudo apt-get update

You can allow the outbound using AWS front-end goto Security Groups -> Outbound

Make sure you select the right group for your AWS instance

Comment: This might be the cause of other issues, but if you see `Hash Sum mismatch` then your instance can contact the outside world, so the firewall is not to blame.